# do i have to sanitize wordpress options when i post per options.php?

Tags: wordpress, sanitization, wordpress-admin

Im writing a cookie notice plugin and im wondering if i need to sanitzie the inputs or escape the outputs of the options when i post / store the options via options.php and use the options via get_option().

i just want to create a safe plugin.

here is an example how i would handle the options:

```
function formz_register_settings()
{
    add_option('formzname', 'guckguck');
    register_setting('formz_settings', 'formzname', 'formz_callback');

}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'formz_register_settings' );


function formz_register_options_page() {
    add_options_page('Page Title', 'FORMZ', 'manage_options', 'formz', 'create_admin_option_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'formz_register_options_page');

function create_admin_option_page(){


    ?>

    <h1>Formulare bearbeiten</h1>
<hr>


    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields('formz_settings'); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="formzname">Facebook Pixel ID</label></th>
            <td><input class="regular-text code" type="text" id="formzname" name="formzname"
                       value="<?php echo esc_html(get_option('formzname')); ?>"/></td>
        </tr>




    </table>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>

    </form>
<br>
    <?php echo esc_html(get_option('formzname')); ?>



<?php

}




?>
```

then i use get_option('bla'); in the frontend to display the settings.

is options.php the right way for that or would be admin-post.php better for it ? and whats the difference ?

basicly i just want to know if my code is allright like that to publish.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WordPress will ensure it's safe to save in the database by escaping the input when the query is run, however it's always best practice to ensure you sanitise it yourself using something like [`sanitize_text_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/).

You can, however in your [`register_setting`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) function call, define the sanitisation method to use when saving it so you don't need to worry about doing it yourself.

*So your code here:*

```
register_setting(
    'formz_settings',
    'formzname',
    'formz_callback'
);
```

*Can be changed to:*

```
register_setting(
    'formz_settings',
    'formzname',
    array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
    )
);
```